# Will verbose arg affected the qp_solver in the python for large scale optimizaiton problem

Tags: python, optimization

I am trying to use qp_solver in python to solve some qp problems using following codes:
`result = solve_qp(H, f, A, b, solver='osqp', max_iter=4000, eps_prim_inf=1e-7, initvals=np.array([0., 0., 0., math.pi / 2.]), verbose = True)`

But it seems the verbose arg will effect the calcuation accuracy. I am wondering if other people met the same issue?

I check the offical document which says it will not affect the accuracy.

I try to comment this arg out and compare the results vs with this arg.
The results are not the same.